# Sorting the words from few words to more words

Tags: r, string

I need to write a function that finds the letter numbers of all words in a given text and sorts the text in accordance with those numbers from words with few letters to words with many letters. Sort the words containing the same number of letters alphabetically.

For having text, you may use Sentences in `tidyverse`. Select
5 or 6 sentences randomly from Sentences.

**For example,you have these sentences:**

`"We find joy in the simplest things. He wrote down a long list of items. The hail pattered on the burnt brown grass. Screen the porch with woven straw mats. The theft of the pearl pin was kept secret. Sweet words work better than fierce."`

I have tried many functions like `sort()`, `order()` and also created my function. Also tried `word_count()` but it’s not giving me the desired results.

**The expected results are as follows:**

`"a he in of of on we joy pin the the the the the the was down find hail kept list long mats than with work brown burnt grass items pearl porch straw sweet theft words woven wrote better fierce screen secret things pattered simplest"`

Comment: You are probably looking for `nchar`: `sentence <- "We find joy in the simplest things. He wrote down a"; words <- unlist(strsplit(sentence, " ")); words[order(nchar(words))]`

Comment: Welcome to SO Ibar! Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to do your homework for you, though the community is very willing to help you solve problems you encounter whilst doing it for yourself. "You must have made a good faith attempt to solve it yourself. The question must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." For more detail, please refer to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)